# Dynamic page creation not working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to create a page dynamically for each courses that I'm adding in a database. 
I have a `CoursesController` who is taking care of adding, displaying the courses.

So, when I click on a course, it should dynamically create a page for that course and show details in that course page.

In the `route.php` page, I have

```
Route::get('courses/{code}', [ 'as'=>'course-show', 'uses'=>'CoursesController@getShow']);
```

and in the

`CoursesController.php`

```
public function getShow($code){
   return $code;
}
```

And in the `index.blade.php` for CoursesController,

```
<h4><a href="{{ URL::action('course-show', $course->code) }}">{{ $course->name }}</a></h4>
```

Now, It create the link with a unique code (saved in database) and upon clicking there, it takes me to the course page with an error:

`BadMethodCallException
Method [show] does not exist.`

What might be the problem? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you sure this route gets used? what happens if you comment it out?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's not getting used. What might be the problem?

Comment: You probably defined a route before that catches the request first. To say more I'd need to see all your routes.

Comment: If I use {{ URL::action('course-show', $course->code) }}

then I need that above Route to work it.

Comment: Actually I followed this Tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KODY1X895U&index=3&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGTahac3wSifpJEDjxekE0k

Comment: If you mean `URL::route()` then yes, but as you commented on the other question, the generated link isn't really a problem, is it? So for now, just test it by directly entering the address in your browser.

Comment: Yes, the same error occures.

Comment: Do you have any other routes?

Comment: the problem was getShow() method. It should be show()

Comment: Hmm that seems really weird to me, considering you bound the route directly to `getShow`... Anyways, glad you got it working

Comment: Yes, same here. It's may be because I have this too in the route file

Route::resource('courses','CoursesController');

Comment: That is definitely the reason. That's why I wanted to know your other routes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The getShow() function in your controller should be show().

Also **URL::action()** goes to a controller action.

You probably want **URL::route()**

```
<h4> <a href="{{ URL::route('course-show', $course->code) }}">{{ $course->name }}</a> </h4>
```

or you could do this

```
<h4> <a href="{{ URL::to('courses/', $course->code) }}">{{ $course->name }}</a> </h4>
```

Comment: Don't you mean `URL::route()`?

Comment: The same problem appears. Except that the URl changed to example.com/course-show/CODE. Previously it was example.com/courses/CODE which was what I wanted

Comment: Thank you @lukasgeiter. I will make the appropriate change.

Comment: You might have to rename your getShow() function to show(). Unless in your routes.php file you have Route::controller().

Comment: Yes, that was the problem :) Thanks a lot.